# Unit testing: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, observable, ngrx

I am trying to write a unit test for one of the functions in my component, in this example, it is 'setup'. 'setup' calls another function, 'additionalSetup' which subscribes to the store while doing a pipe(take(1)), and takes the first emission:

```
private setup() {
    // ...declares/assigns a few variables in the component
    this.additionalSetup() ;
}

private additionalSetup() {
    this.store.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(/*logic here, but you get the idea*/);
}
```

My unit test seems to fail with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Within the 'setup' unit test, I've tried to mock the 'additionalSetup':

```
component.additionalSetup = jest.fn();
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am fairly new to jest and I am still learning. What approach would I take to resolve this error?

Comment: `this.store` is `undefined` for whatever reason when you invoke that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is already created, so it already had invoked `component.additionalSetup`.
You'll have to mock `additionalSetup` before creating the component in order to solve the problem.

This can easily be done with the  [`Angular Testing Library`](https://github.com/testing-library/angular-testing-library/)

```
 const component = await render(MyComponent, {
    componentProperties: {
      additionalSetup : jest.fn(),
    },
  });
```

Or you could implement this [yourself](https://github.com/testing-library/angular-testing-library/blob/master/projects/testing-library/src/lib/testing-library.ts#L171)